# What is the best to represent List in protobuff?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm converting XML based service into Protobuff based service. I stuck at a point where I am unable to decide how to represent List in proto messages. For example I have message like

```
message Person{
 string name=1;
 repeated Address address =2;
}
```

When I generate xml from above message usign protobuff-java-format, I got

```
<Person>
    <name>Nathan Drake</name>
    <address>1234L, XXX, YY - 1234</address>
    <address>7896B, XXX, YY - 1234</address>
</Person>
```

but I want

```
<Person>
    <name>Nathan Drake</name>
    <address-list>
     <address>1234L, XXX, YY - 1234</address>
     <address>7896B, XXX, YY - 1234</address>
    </address-list>
</Person>
```

Code is working fine with with repeated field in the Person message, but is it good practice to wrap the in another List message?

```
message Person{
 string name=1;
 AddreeList addressList=2
}

message AddressList{
 repeated Address address =1;
}
```

Comment: It's a totally reasonable practice, if that's the structure of the data you want.

Comment: Also, I felt kinda strange when I'm adding address to person object in java like Person.newBuider.addAddress(Address.newBuilder.build()).build(). Where I supposed to add address to address list.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need or advantage in doing so, unless your list itself can have properties of it's own. Since you want a `<address-list>`, that isn't impossible, so: feel free to include an extra layer if you want. Just note that it isn't *necessary*, unless you later need to store:

```
<address-list someExtraInfo="abc">
```

which might correspond to:

```
message AddressList{
   optional someExtraInfo string = 2;
   repeated Address address = 1;
}
```